# CSS DIv is Below Gradient?

Tags: html, css

I basically have a gradient on the body of my webpage and the navbar is at the top like it should be, but the div that I have is below the entire gradient. You literally have to scroll all the way down to see the div. Any ideas on how to get the div over the gradient? Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> navbar}}
  <div id="center">
    <h1>Bobcats Services</h1>
    <h2>Everything you need!</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#00b7ea+0,009ec3+100;Blue+3D+%2315 */
  background: rgb(0,183,234); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,183,234,1) 0%, rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,183,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,183,234,1) 0%,rgba(0,158,195,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

#center {
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #008fc8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: From Tyler Roper: 'In order for this to be answered you'll need to share the HTML.'

Comment: @RushyPanchal Updated.

Comment: Are you loading it in as a template? Inspect element to see if it is in fact where you'd expect it.

Comment: @GHOST-34 Thanks, figured it out with your help. Apparently my navbar was taking up the entire page, got it fixed and thanks once again!